# Why are two getchar() functions used?

Tags: c, getchar

I'm trying to write a program which task is to get rid of extra whitespace in a text stream.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    
    while( (c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == ' ')
        {
            putchar(c);
            while( (c = getchar()) == ' ' );
            
            if(c == EOF) break;
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

I know that `getchar()` function returns a new character each iteration and we store the character in the `c` variable, but I can't figure out why do we need to assign `c` variable to `getchar()` in the second while loop again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop loops as long as it extracts spaces from the stream, effectively skipping them. The result is that, if you have a sequence of spaces, the first one will be printed, and the rest will be discarded.

You need to assign to `c` even there (as opposed to just doing something like `while (getchar() == ' ');`) because you'll reach a point where you extract a character that is not a space, so you need to remember what character it was to output it after the loop.

Comment: So if I type in the first ```while``` loop ```Hello\b\b\bWorld```, the ```H``` char is going to be iterated. But what chars will be iterated in the second loop?

Comment: @RodionIskhakov: No.  The outer while loop will read H, e, l, l, o and then a space; at that point, the inner loop takes over, and reads the second space (which it doesn't print) and then gets W, which breaks the inner loop.  Since W is not EOF, the outer loop continues and prints W, and then reads o, r, l, d and probably newline (but that's not a space so it doesn't get any special treatment).  Maybe it then gets EOF because you indicate EOF (by typing control-D on Unix or control-Z on Windows).  Or it continues with the next line of input, up until it does reach EOF.

Comment: @RodionIskhakov: note that in C, `\b` is the escape sequence for backspace, which is wholly unrelated to a space.  We can guess your meaning, but it is confusing in general.  If you said "using `\b` for blanks", there'd be no problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that `getchar()` function returns a new character each iteration
> and we store the character in the `c` variable, but I can't figure out
> why do we need to assign `c` variable to `getchar()` in the second while
> loop again.

The reuse of variable `c` is of no particular consequence.  A separate variable could have been used for the inner loop instead.  Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    
    while( (c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);
        if(c == ' ')
        {
            int c2;
            while( (c2 = getchar()) == ' ' );
            
            if (c2 == EOF) break;
            putchar(c2);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that a rearrangement of the `putchar()` calls was required.  Either way, when the program encounters a run of spaces, it must both (i) print one space, AND (ii) avoid losing the first non-space, if any, after the run.

It would also have been possible to write the program with only one appearance of a call to `getchar()`, but then it would need to store more state explicitly (whether the previous character read was a space) and use that to decide whether to output each newly-read character.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c;
    _Bool was_space = 0;
    
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != ' ' || !was_space) {
            putchar(c);
        }
        was_space = (c == ' ');
    }
}
```

In fact, I find both of those alternatives rather clearer than the original.  The original seems to go out of its way to minimize the number of variable it declares.

Comment: In the first ```while``` loop I put, for example, ```Hello\b\b\bWorld``` and this will be saved in ```c``` variable. My question is, why in the second ```while``` loop the text doesn't need to be rewrote, because we assigned a new variable to ```getchar()```?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, @RodionIskhakov.  However the details are structured, the program does the same thing: read one character at a time; if the character is not a space then print it and move on to the next; if that character *is* a space, then print it and consume all additional space characters that follow.  Consuming spaces after the first necessarily ends in one of two ways: the end of the file is reached, or a non-space is read.  In the latter case, the program must ensure that that non-space is printed and not lost.